# what type of model should I use?

Tags: statistics

I am trying to assess the infuence of sex (nominal), altitude (nominal) and latitude (nominal) on corrected wing size (continuous; residual of wing size by body mass) of an animal species. I considered altitude as a nominal factor  given the fact that this particular species is mainly distributed at the extremes (low and high) of steep elevational gradients in my study area. I also considered latitude as a nominal fixed factor given the fact that I have sampled individuals only at three main latitudinal levels (north, center and south).

I have been suggested to use Linear Mixed Model for this analysis. Specifically, considering sex, altitude, latitude, sex:latitude, sex:altitude, and altitude:latitude as fixed factors, and collection site (nominal) as the random effect. The latter given the clustered distribution of the collection sites.

However, I noticed that despite the corrected wing size follow a normal distribution, it violates the assumption of homoscedasticity among some altitudinal/latitudinal groups. I tried to use a non-parametric equivalent of factorial ANOVA (ARTool) but I cannot make it run because it does not allow cases of missing data and it requires to asses all possible fixed factor and their interactions. I will appreciate any advice on what type of model I can use given the design of my data and what software/package can I use to perform the analysis.

Thanks in advance for your kind attention.

Regards,

Comment: In R linear mixed models (LMMs) are often fitted with [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) or the newer [glmmTMB](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/index.html). There are no restrictions that the data is balanced. How many collections sites are there?

Comment: Hi @diptkov, thanks for your response. There were 24 collection sites: 4 from low altitude-north, 4 from low-altitude center, 4 from low-altitude south, 2 from high-altitude north, 2 from high-altitude center, and 3 from high-altitude south. I collected from 2-6 individuals in each site.

Comment: You have individuals nested within sites; a mixed effects model can handle this structure. I'm not sure why the outcome is wing size corrected for body mass (instead of wing size with body mass a covariate in the model together with the other variables). Anyway, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/228800/237901) for more about nested random effects and [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) for more about LMMs in R. If you have questions about the statistics, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask them.